# Convert C/C++ to 8086/88 Assembly

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, assembly, x86-16

Is there any way to convert C/C++ to Assembly not to HEX.

Not like something that gcc or other compiler done(C/C++ --> ASM --> HEX).

Only Convert It to ASM.

Is there any way to do it by gcc,I mean stop compiler when translate C/C++ to ASM?

with special thanks for your attention,and so sorry for my basic question

Comment: Hex? You mean that binary encoding of machine code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `-S` option of gcc, for example:

```
gcc -S hello.c
```

This will give you a file `hello.s` with assembly instructions.

Comment: I'd only add that you can specify the assembly dialect (INTEL vs AT&T) with `-masm=intel` or `-masm=att`.

Comment: @Mrafcho001 is there any way to add special INTEL processor like 8086?

Comment: @Moein7tl Are you trying to compile some code such that it would run on an 8086? If so, I believe you're trying to cross-compile. This means you're going to have to setup a cross-compiling toolchain. I dont have any experience with doing that, but I'm sure google will turn something useful up.

Comment: Adding `-fverbose-asm` may also be worthwhile.

Comment: @Moein7tl, gcc has a lot of options to emit code that is tuned to a specific target processor with the `--arch=something` option. gcc.gnu.org has all the information that you are looking for.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that gcc *cannot* generate 8086/8088 machine code --- it can only target 32-bit platforms, i.e. 80386 or later.

Answer (score 4):

```
gcc -O2 -S -c foo.c
```

will leave the generated assembly code on the file foo.s.